# How to run app from VC++ without debug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-express

I'm trying to learn to love Visual C++ 2010 Express, but it is difficult! I've just created a "Hello world" console app and compiled it - no problems. I now want to run it. It seems the only option open to me is to run it in the debugger - there is a "Run" button on the toolbar but it is disabled. I don't want to debug it - I really don't like debuggers! Is there any way of just running the app from inside the VS IDE?

Comment: Is there a "Start Without Debugging" command under the "Debug" menu?

Comment: The debugger is... a lot like an oscilloscope, what's not to like ;-)

Comment: @James No there isn't - I've seen this in VC#, but VC++ doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: @Chris I have a lot of reasons for not using the debugger. If VC++ can only run stuff that way, so be it, but I won't be using it.

Comment: It is present in the Visual C++ IDE in other SKUs (e.g. Visual Studio Ultimate); I am surprised it is not there in the Express SKU.  I've not used the Express SKU though, so I don't really know for sure.

Comment: I am retagging this as [tag:visual-studio-express] as Visual C++ has "Start without Debugging".

Comment: Doesn't Express have some form of "Continue"? So even if the app starts with the debugger attached you can just have it advance without manual intervention.

Comment: @Andrei - that's fine but not the same as no debugging.  Running with debugging alters the process's behaviour eg. heap ops are checked and slower, and so on

Comment: @Steve: then may I recommend Start\Run\path to app? It's bound to be simpler, also mimics how the "end user" will run the app and removes anything VC++ might do behind the scenes even in case of "Start without Debugging" (probably nothing, though)

Comment: @Andrei- yes, but that's out of scope for the original question here.  In any case, I see it's been answered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can't see the "Start Without Debugging" command in the toolbar, go to "Tools -> Settings -> Expert Settings". Basic Settings hides lots of stuff you probably want to see.

Professional version of VC2010 doesn't seem to have this switch.

Comment: @Neil: Good question :)... I am not exactly a C++-expert but I want most of the stuff it hides.

Comment: Interestingly, after doing this, that disabled "Run" button I mentioned in my question has vanished! I wonder what the hell it was supposed to do? But I guess I can customise myself a new one.

Comment: @Neil: Are you talking about the green "play" icon? Sounds like a bug though.

Comment: No, it's a button with the text "Run" and no icon on it. Oh, wait a minute, it couldn't be that they have put a CAPTION at the beginning of the toolbar. Please no!

Answer (score 4):

- Open the Tools menu
- Go to Customize
- Switch to the Commands tab
- Select the Debug category
- Drag the "Start Without Debugging" command to the Debug menu item

Edit: Full disclosure, I don't actually have VC++2010 Express installed on this computer, so I'm just sort of winging it here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a "Start Without Debugging" icon on the menu bar instead of in the drop-down Debug menu (even if Tools->Settings = "Basic Settings"), do this:

**Tools->Customize->Commands->(choose Menu bar)->Add Command->Debug->Start Without Debugging->ok**.

Then Move Up/Down if you want to change its position.